# Css link targeting, should i use a or :link

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i've recently been working with 3rd party code targeting a button class differently across :link and input. I'd like to rein in this section of css so i'm looking for what in most cases is considered best practice.

As it stands an input button is targeted like this

```
input.button {
 ...
}
```

And a link button is targeted using the :link pseudo class

```
.button:link:after{
content: "...";
}
```

instead of

```
a.button:after{
content: "...";
}
```

As far as i can think the :link pseudo class only refers to an `<a>` tag so is there any advantage of using `.button:link` over `a.button`?

Comment: These are two different CSS rules one targeting unvisited link and the other just an anchor with button class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:link` selects an `a` element whose `href` property has not been visited.

If your `a` element has a `href` property which you have not visited before, `.button:link` will select the same element as `a.button`, however if it either has not been visited before or does not have a `href` property, `.button:link` will select nothing.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/L3Xw5/2/).

Further reading: [W3's CSS Selector documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#the-link-pseudo-classes-link-and-visited).

---

As Ruirize mentioned in comments on this answer, the `:link` pseudo-class selector also selects visited links on Google Chrome. I've raised this as a bug on Chrome's bug tracker, which can be [viewed here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=346255).

Comment: `:link` actually targets both. The default `:visited` selector overrides your style. http://jsfiddle.net/L3Xw5/3/

Comment: @Ruirize it shouldn't - this must be a browser-specific bug. The official specification which I've linked as "Further Reading" in my answer states: "The `:link` pseudo-class **applies to links that have not yet been visited.**"

Comment: It functions how I described in `Blink`/`Webkit` and `Gecko`. Oddly enough `Trident` gets it right.

Comment: My answer here is correct in terms of code validity (and shouldn't have been downvoted).

Comment: @Ruirize I've created a ticket on Chrome's bug tracker and modified my answer to include a note about this. If it was you who downvoted this answer then I kindly ask that you reverse this, as my answer when conforming to standards is correct.

Comment: I've also gone and created an issue on the Mozilla tracker. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=976019

Comment: @JamesDonnelly https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=976019 Interestingly it looks like it's that way because of security, which does make sense and still fits the spec.

Comment: @Ruirize: Looks like the properties both of you are testing are inconsistent with the ones in the question, hence the confusion. In particular the one in this answer completely fails to demonstrate the behavior that is stated for that reason, and I probably should not have upvoted it at first. I can't remove my upvote, and bump-editing the answer just to do so would be poor form, but I trust that the answer will be corrected anyway so my upvote can stay.

Comment: so it sounds like that to make sure that all <a> tags are consistently targeted the best method in this case is target with both the <a> tag and the :link like this `a.button:link`

Comment: @wellhairy ideally you should select on both `:link` and `:visited`. There's no need to specify `a` either, unless you're doing that for specificity reasons: `.button:link, .button:visited { ... }`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Ah yeah sorry I understand I have target the `:visited` separately. I was thinking because the `a` targets `a` tags without `hrefs` it might be good practice to target the `a` as well as the `:link`. What i meant to write was `a.button, a.button:link` but I cant think of any reason you might have an `a` tag without a `href`? So i guess your right in saying that theres no need to specify the `a` tag at all.